# updating two different salaries (value) in a table with single sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have to update the salary of employeees having salary as 0 by 1000 and other than 0 by 500 with a single sql query.
How we can do that.
Please suggest.

Comment: you have shown no effort.  This is not how this site works. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query:-

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET salary = CASE  WHEN (salary = 0)  THEN salary + 1000   
                  WHEN (salary > 0)  THEN salary + 500 END
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table emp
(id number,
 sal number
 );

 insert into emp values (1,0);
 insert into emp values (2,10);
 insert into emp values (3,0);
 insert into emp values (4,-1);

update emp
set sal = case when sal = 0 Then 1000
               when sal != 0 Then 500
           END
```

Second condition put it as `!=0`  by assuming it can be either `greater or less or null`
Hope this help. Next time show your effort also.